# Duplicate screen over many (5+) screens using DisplayPort

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, splitter

I'm setting up for an event, and there will be multiple monitors around (around 5 - 10 monitors). I want to display the same screen on all monitors.

My computer does not support that many monitors directly connected to it. So (from my understanding), I need to use a splitter.

If I was using HDMI, I could buy an [eight port HDMI splitter](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/165224323576?chn=ps&_ul=AU&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1_pxwFoaKSI2wndHFRZlg_g98&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=705-139619-5960-0&mkcid=2&mkscid=101&itemid=165224323576&targetid=&device=m&mktype=pla&googleloc=9071263&poi=&campaignid=15984321586&mkgroupid=&rlsatarget=&abcId=9300814&merchantid=119337481&gclid=CjwKCAiAl9efBhAkEiwA4TorihBBhKkrqC3nr9LxWvdFHz4v5Zi-p6X0EIdUbOe8PpMlQtHVvKQboBoCjygQAvD_BwE).

But some of my screens only support DisplayPort (the HDMI port broke). All the DisplayPort splitters I can find use MST, which (if I understand correctly), requires the graphics card to handle each screen separately.

Main question: **Is it possible to have a DisplayPort splitter, that lets multiple screens behave like one screen?**

Side question: Will there be issues using an active HDMI to DisplayPort adapter in a HDMI splitter?

Comment: Even when the screens are identified as independent you can always set them as mirrors in any desktop OS. Indeed, when using splitters typically it's interpreted as a single screen but DisplayPort allows daisychaining.

Comment: Connecting these monitors to the HDMI splitter with HDMI-to-DisplayPort cables requires testing. A categorical answer is perhaps not possible.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The screens can only be mirrored in the OS if the GPU supports that many screens. Admittedly, for my use case, I could bring the couple screens that have broken DisplayPort back to the desktop and mirror them, and have everything else run on a splitter. But I'm still curious if DisplayPort splitters exist.